# How to disable onclick of first Navdrawer items in navigation drawerfragment

Tags: java, android

I want to disable onclick of firstnavdrawer item permantly..
 if i click of first navdraweritem...it should not perform onclick  operation....how to achieve this in below code

[image]

```
   mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

// load slide menu items
navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

// nav drawer icons from resources
navMenuIcons = getResources()
        .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

// adding nav drawer items to array
// Home
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
// Find People
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
// Photos
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
// Communities, Will add a counter here
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
// Pages
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
// What's hot, We  will add a counter here
navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));


// Recycle the typed array
navMenuIcons.recycle();

mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

// setting the nav drawer list adapter
adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
        navDrawerItems);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter)
```

Comment: Post SlideMenuClickListener code

Comment: btnSlide.setOnClickListener(new ClickListenerForScrolling(scrollView, menu));

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable click on "Home" item of navigation drawer then you should do that from "activity_main_drawer.xml" file. like this

```
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:title="Home" />
```

Comment: i am not added items like this ...i created string.xml...in thiere  <string-array name="nav_drawer_items">Home </item>..i created like this...see my above code..we have to do programatically...i dont know how to write

Comment: Try this then:
NavigationView  navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setEnabled(false);

Comment: from whr you took this id... findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

Comment: You haven't used NavigationView in activity xml?

Comment: No...i am not used

Comment: I think you are doing this through list view... Please try this.

    listview.getChildAt(selectedPosition).setEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0):

Find that menu item and setEnble(false).
yourNavView.getMenu();
Then find item from that menu.